# How to transfer whatsapp data without backup

Tags: iphone, storage, whatsapp.app

I want to transfer whatsapp data to another iPhone, but I can’t make a backup due to a lack of storage.

[image]

I have deleted all what is in my iPhone, but it still shows the message “there is no enough space”, it seems “Other” or the system files fill up my iphone.

[image]

Are there other ways to transfer the data ?

Comment: Have you tried a simple restart?

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question about how to transfer the WhatsApp data or how to make space on your iPhone (in order to perform a WhatsApp backup)?

Comment: @josh i have tried that , but still

Comment: @fsb my question is about anyway to transfer the data, even if that is a way to free space on my iphone (i have tried many ways i found but I couldn’t change the “others” space)

Comment: https://www.imore.com/how-find-and-remove-other-files-iphone-and-ipad

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a full iOS backup and restore onto the other iPhone, if you are going to be using that iPhone as well. That will copy everything over so you can have not just your whatsapp info but the other application and user data.

That is the most efficient way to accomplish what you are asking for.